# React nested Map and Filter (filter out duplicates)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi Ive just started using react and have kinda hit a brick wall on mapping an array.

```
const fullMen = LocationMenuStore.menuItems['menu']['headings'].map((headings: any) => {
            <Typography>{headings['heading_name']}</Typography>

            return LocationMenuStore.menuItems['menu']['sub_headings'].map((subHeadings: any) => {
                if (subHeadings['menu_heading_id'] === headings['id']) {
                    <Typography>{subHeadings['sub_heading_name']}</Typography>

                    return LocationMenuStore.menuItems['menu']['items'].map((items: any) => {
                        if(items['sub_heading_id'] === subHeadings['id']){
                            <Typography>{items['item_name']}</Typography>
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        });
```

I'm fetching data from an API which returns something like below

```
menu: { 
   headings: [
      {
         "id": 2,
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "is_active": 0,
         "heading_name": "Drinks"
      },
   ]
   sub_headings: [
      { 
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "menu_heading_id": 2,
         "is_active": 0,
         "sub_heading_name": "Beers",
      },
      { 
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "menu_heading_id": 2,
         "is_active": 0,
         "sub_heading_name": "White Wines",
      }
   ]
   items: [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "heading_id": 2,
         "sub_heading_id": 1,
         "is_active": 0,
         "item_name": "Harp",
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "heading_id": 2,
         "sub_heading_id": 1,
         "is_active": 0,
         "item_name": "Coors",
      },
   ]
}
```

but to the user, I would like to display it like this

```
- Heading (Drinks)
-- Sub Heading (Beers)
---- Item (Miller)
---- Item (Coors)
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to map over them properly, I can map headings ok but the moment I try to nest the map function I can't see anything and if I manage to get some kind of output, there are duplicates.

Is there a way to map everything and filter out duplicates, plus display it correctly?

Comment: On line one of the first snippet you declare a `<Typography>` but don't include it in the result of the map. This seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that your .map() statements are not returning the JSX that is being generated. Example codesandbox that illustrates this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dream-lrtk8?file=/src/App.js

In addition, I would also highly recommend you to key these components with a unique ID. You can read more about keying components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

You did not return `heading_name` and `sub_heading_name`

Use `.map() v => ())` instead of `.map(v => {})`

Comment: I'm using typescript which is why I have the temporary type set to any for now, so using --- .map() v => ()) --- would give an error. You're way is good and that's what I would normally do but doing it like ```.map(v => {}) ``` allows me to add conditionals which I need so I can match sub_headings to headings and items to sub_headings or items to headings. Thanks for the comment though :)

Comment: Also you can do this: `() => { return (<Component />) }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick render function I created using your dataset, you can redo this into a separate function. The main reason for your issue is that you haven't returned the JSX.

**Also noted that in the dataset you provided, the sub_heading object does not have an 'id' property, maybe it was a mistake.**

```
menuJSON = { 
   headings: [
      {
         "id": 2,
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "is_active": 0,
         "heading_name": "Drinks"
      },
   ]
   sub_headings: [
      { 
         "id": 1,
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "menu_heading_id": 2,
         "is_active": 0,
         "sub_heading_name": "Beers",
      },
      { 
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "menu_heading_id": 2,
         "is_active": 0,
         "sub_heading_name": "White Wines",
      }
   ]
   items: [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "heading_id": 2,
         "sub_heading_id": 1,
         "is_active": 0,
         "item_name": "Harp",
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "business_id": 1,
         "location_id": 1,
         "menu_id": 1,
         "heading_id": 2,
         "sub_heading_id": 1,
         "is_active": 0,
         "item_name": "Coors",
      },
   ]
}
render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.menuJSON['headings'].map((heading) => {
              return(<div>{heading['heading_name']}
              {this.menuJSON['sub_headings'].map((subHeading) => {
                  if(subHeading['menu_heading_id'] === heading['id']){
                    return(<div>{subHeading['sub_heading_name']}
                      {this.menuJSON['items'].map((item) => {
                          if(item['sub_heading_id'] === subHeading['id']){
                            return(<div>{item['item_name']}</div>)
                          }else{
                            return(<div></div>)
                          }
                      })}
                    </div>)
                  }else{
                    return(<div></div>)
                  }
              })}
              </div>)
            })
            }
          </div>
        )
      }
```